What is the most elegant way to produce Linear Regression metrics such as p-values after fitting with sklearn?
Excel provides a full printout of betas, p-values, F-values, R², etc. However, when I use sklearn's LinearRegression, it does not calculate p-values for me. I then have to use statsmodels to get all the statistics that Excel provides out of the box.
What is the most elegant way to get all the statistics after fitting a model using sklearn? Currently, I fit the model twice: first with sklearn, then with statsmodels.
 import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Example data
X = np.random.rand(100, 3)  # Features
y = np.random.rand(100)     # Target

# Fit the model using sklearn
model = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)

# Extract betas
betas = model.coef_
intercept = model.intercept_

# Add a constant to X for statsmodels
X_const = sm.add_constant(X)

# Fit the model using statsmodels for p-values
sm_model = sm.OLS(y, X_const).fit()
p_values = sm_model.pvalues

# Print betas and p-values
print("Betas (coefficients):", betas)
print("Intercept:", intercept)
print("P-values:", p_values)


Why bother fitting in sklearn at all?

In many cases, you might not need sklearn at all. Then just train and use a statsmodels model. Note that statmodels and sklearn might optimize in a different way and come to different result.
If you need sklearn
You can implement a wrapper around statsmodels that allows to integrate it into sklearn processes (e.g. into a Pipeline or for cross validation).
A good start (taken from here) would be:
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator

class StatsModelsEstimator(BaseEstimator):

  def __init__(self, model_class, **init_params):
    self.model_class = model_class
    self.init_params = init_params

  def fit(self, X, y, **fit_params):
    self.model_ = self.model_class(endog = y, exog = X, **self.init_params)
    fit_method = fit_params.pop("fit_method", "fit")
    self.results_ = getattr(self.model_, fit_method)(**fit_params)
    return self

  def predict(self, X, **predict_params):
    return self.results_.predict(exog = X, **predict_params)

which would allow you calls like
from statsmodels.api import OLS

estimator = StatsModelsEstimator(OLS)
estimator.fit(X, y, fit_method = "fit_regularized")

print(estimator.results_.summary())

Of course this is just a start. Sklearn has some rules how to build sklearn-compatible estimators (see for example the official documentation)

You can just call the summary method on the fitted model
sm_model = sm.OLS(y, X_const).fit()
print(sm_model.summary())

